# Parallel Port Output On Windows XP using Qt4 and C++

Tags: c++, qt4, windows-xp, parallel-processing

I have a hardware device which is controlled via a parallel port connection to a PC running Windows XP. I am coding in Qt4 and C++ (Qt Creator) and need a way to output to the device over the parallel port. All information I have found so far references companies and websites that closed down 5 or so years ago.

Does anyone have any suggestions or example code on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Searching for `WinAPI paralel port` returned a lot of valid results.

Comment: Oh yeah?  Do any of them doing anything that works?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [inpout32.dll](http://electrosofts.com/parallel/parallelwin.html).

I've used this DLL in several different API's (from old Borland's OWL, VCL and even dirty MFC). To use it with Qt is quite simple. Even more if you don't need input events, but just output data.

Follow the given example and let me know if you have any trouble. The main points of interest are the `_inp()` and `_outp()` functions.

Read more [here](http://www.beyondlogic.org/porttalk/porttalk.htm) and a lot of information can also be found [here](http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm).

- Remember that this is *not* portable! this solution might be encapsulated in classes to allow OS decoupling if you need to port it to a non-windows app.